# Logging in to the copy of the WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I've created a developer copy of an existing WordPress-based website, to test something safely.

I updated the wp-config.php file to include info on the new database, database user, etc. (the exact copy of the original database, but renamed).

When I log in to wp-admin, however, I'm being automatically redirected to the login to the login page for the original website. What should I edit to be able to log in into the copy site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may log in to mysql database via phpadmin.
Then goto WP_options table and change the site url

Comment: Yes, I'd gladly do that if I could log in to the admin panel. But what I am unable to do is precisely log in to the admin panel of the correct website! That is actually what I am asking about, @Santosh – how can I log in to the copy site. ;-) Would be grateful for your further suggestion!

Comment: Table `WP_options` if you have not done any changes to default tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding/editing this in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Another thought is to edit the `wp_options` table in the development database. Locate the `option_name` column and browse for `siteurl` and `home` and update their values accordingly.

More Info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: I tried that, thank you, @Dwight. The site crashed as a result. Would appreciate more suggestions!